# NodeEntity wont persist

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j-4, request-mapping

I have the following NodeEntity:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Book")
public class Book{
  private Long id;
  private String content;

  @Relationship(direction = Relationship.OUTGOING, type="WRITTEN_BY")
  private User author;
}
```

where `User` is

```
@NodeEntity(label = "User)
public class User{
  private Long id;
  private String username;
}
```

and the `BookRepository`

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends GraphRepository<Book> {
}
```

I've build a simple Rest-Controller to store a `Book` in the DB.

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(path = "/books", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Transactional
public class BookController {

  @Autowired
  private BookRepository bookRepo;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public Book createBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
    return bookRepo.save(book);
  }
```

When I now `POST` a Book the JSON

```
{
  "content":"Test content",
  "author":{
    "username":"Test-Username"
  }
}
```

to the controller, two things happen that confuse me:
First, the author in the book-object is null, although both the `Book` and the `User` have their default constructor.
Secoundly: The Book doesn't get persisted. There is no error, I just get the same book-object returned (with the author still null) but still with a null id.
Querying `MATCH n RETURN n` on the neo4j client also yields nothing.

I tried removing the `User` object from the `Book, thinking the fault was there, but I still get the same behavior.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes talking about a problem alone solves it... I've forgotten to put the package that contained the Book into the

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  return new SessionFactory(/*Package of Book should have been here*/);
}
```

in the `Application`